# How to make Atomic Pi with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Chrome play YouTube videos

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, intel-atom

I bought the Atomic Pi and changed the (very buggy) OS to Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I can do everything I want with it except one thing: play YouTube videos. For some reason the video just keeps showing the loading circle.

I've tried everything I found on the internet including installing MPV, VLC, installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Is this a general problem with the Atom processor? can Intel Atom x5-Z8350 play YouTube videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Lubuntu 19.04 it will work without any config mod's.  HDMI audio works from the start and Youtube videos play well.  It's possible HDMI audio works with v19.04 also with other desktops... Ubuntu, Xubuntu, ext.
If you have to use 18.04 then probably, to at least get audio working, you will have to modify things via "Linuxium ISO respin script" or manually change the installation/configuration.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 19.04 and it worked, I can play up to 1080p 30fps or 720p 60fps Youtube videos.
Maybe with Lubuntu 19.04 I would have been able to play up to 1080p 60fps Youtube videos.